# Rerun file not found to execute failed feature scenario in cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, cucumber, cucumber-java

Hi StackoverFlow folks,

The below error is really eating my head and I am not able to understand whats the mistake I have made. Hence looking forward to communities help.

Command and error
`home:tcr-ui-automation sobhit.sharma$ gradle clean build -Denv=QA '-Dcucumber.options=--tags @target/rerun.txt'`

> Task :test

`runners.TestRunner STANDARD_OUT None of the features at [classpath:features] matched the filters: [@target/rerun.txt]`

```
0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.000s
```

`

The cucumber option is something like this where I have defined my options-

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "classpath:features",glue = "stepDefinations",
        plugin = { "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:",
                "junit:target/cucumber-results.xml",
                "rerun:target/rerun.txt"},
        tags="@Smoke",
        monochrome = true
)
public class TestRunner {
```

Goal is to run the failed scenarios of a feature file.
File structure-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with errors that don't seem to make sense, it often helps to read every part of the command and error message out loud and in detail. Think if it as carefully explaining what you are doing to a co-worker.

For example:

```
gradle clean build -Denv=QA '-Dcucumber.options=--tags @target/rerun.txt'
```

Here you are telling gradle to clean the build environment. After cleaning the build environment to build the project. When doing so a JVM flag is passed to set the environment to QA and a JVM flag is passed to tell Cucumber to run only scenarios that are tagged with `@target/rerun.txt`.

When executing this:

```
None of the features at [classpath:features] matched the filters: [@target/rerun.txt]
```

Now Cucumber complains that it looked for features on the classpath but none were tagged with `@target/rerun.txt`.